# PieExploded in newer versions

Tags: graphics, customization, charts

I am trying to explode one segment of a pie chart. How does this work in version 10. PieExploded is obsolete now. Can't find out how to use SectorSpacing for this.
Many thanks for a hint.

Comment: Provide some code of what you have tried.

Comment: You can click on a segment to achieve the effect. But I do not know how to do this programmatically.  +1!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I want to do it programmatically. I clicked on a segment and wanted to find out with CNTRL E to find the code snipped. But it looked far to complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dynamic variables controlling the popout state of each segment are initialised to `False` in the `DynamicModule` container. If you alter the initialisation for a segment to `True` it will start in the popped out state.

This is a crude way to do that:

```
explode[pc_, i_] := ReplacePart[pc, Position[pc, False][[i]] -> True]

PieChart[{1, 2, 3}] ~explode~ 2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation and roundabout. But isn't that astonishing, that there is (no longer) a simple option for that.

Comment: @Darwin1871 I'm surprised there isn't a wrapper function for it like `Callout` or `Labeled`