# Axes Labeling in Bar Charts

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, charts

How do I label a bar chart such that a list produced by Mathematica such as `{{7, 0.0446108}, {5, 0.074924}, {2, 0.0778787}, {3, 0.0778787}, {1, 0.0798332}, {9, 0.0805987}, {10, 0.0805987}, {e, 0.0821453}, {8, 0.11312}, {4, 0.14265}, {6, 0.145762}}` has the bar chart labeled from smallest to largest bar with numbers 7,5,2,3,1,9,10,e,8,4,6 appear in that order from left to right on the horizontal axis with the heights of the bars, e.g., 0.0778787 along the vertical axes.

```
Clear[AA, BB]
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 
   5 <-> 6, 7 <-> 6, 6 <-> 8, 8 <-> 9, 8 <-> 10, 9 <-> e, 10 <-> e};
AA = PageRankCentrality[edges]
BB = Sort[AA]
SortBy[{VertexList[edges], 
   PageRankCentrality[edges]}\[Transpose], Last]
PieChart[BB, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", ChartLabels -> Automatic];
BarChart[BB, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 
  5 <-> 6, 7 <-> 6, 6 <-> 8, 8 <-> 9, 8 <-> 10, 9 <-> e, 10 <-> e};
prc = PageRankCentrality[edges]
```

> {0.0798,0.0778,0.0778,0.1426,0.0749,0.1457,0.04461,0.1131,0.08059,0.08059,0.08214}

```
ordering = Ordering @ prc;
```

**GraphPropertyChart**

`` GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart `` gives a layout that combines a pie chart of vertex properties with a graph of edges:

```
gpc = GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[
 Graph[VertexList[edges][[ordering]], edges], 
 Automatic -> prc[[ordering]], EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05]], 
 ChartStyle->"DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

Click on a vertex to get the incident edges highlighted:
[image]

Or use the function `explode` from [this answer by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138105/125) to highlight incident edges for selected vertices:

```
explode[pc_, i_] := ReplacePart[pc, Position[pc, False][[i]] -> True]
explode[gpc, VertexIndex[g, #] & /@ {10,3, 6}]
```

[image]

Additional examples:

```
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[Graph[VertexList[edges][[ordering]], edges], 
  Automatic -> prc[[ordering]],
  ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["NoiseSector", 
   "AngularFrequency" -> 5, "RadialAmplitude" -> .2], 
  ChartLabels -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ VertexList[edges][[ordering]]), ChartStyle -> 63] /. 
 {False -> True , Text[x_, pos_] :> {FaceForm[White], Disk[pos, .7], Text[x, pos]}}
```

[image]

With a different `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["TriangleWaveSector", 
   "AngularFrequency" -> 10, "RadialAmplitude" -> .5]
```

[image]

```
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[Graph[edges], 
  Automatic -> ConstantArray[1, VertexCount[edges]], 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05]]]
```

[image]

```
bwc = BetweennessCentrality[Graph[edges]];
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[
  Graph[VertexList[edges][[Ordering[bwc]]], edges], Automatic -> Sort[bwc], 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05]]]
```

[image]

**PieChart**

```
PieChart[prc[[ordering]], ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
 SectorOrigin -> {{2 Pi, "Counterclockwise"}, 1},
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, 16] & /@ VertexList[edges][[ordering]], "RadialCallout"]]
```

[image]

**BarChart**

```
BarChart[prc[[ordering]], ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
 ChartLabels -> VertexList[edges][[ordering]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Combining `BarChart` with `Graph` to produce  something similar to the output of `GraphPropertyChart`:

```
gr1 = Graph[VertexList[edges][[ordering]], edges];
graph = SetProperty[gr1, 
  {ImageSize -> 500, GraphLayout -> {"LinearEmbedding", Method -> "SpectralOrdering"}, 
    VertexCoordinates -> Thread[{Range[VertexCount@gr1], 0}]}];

bc = BarChart[20 prc[[ordering]], 
   ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, 20] & /@ VertexList[gr1], Top], 
   ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", BarSpacing -> .2, BarOrigin -> Top, 
   Axes -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 500];
Show[bc, graph]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
data = SortBy[{VertexList[edges],PageRankCentrality[edges]}\[Transpose], N@*Last]
BarChart[BB, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow",ChartLabels -> First /@ data]
```

Comment: Alan ... Many thanks for your quick and very helpful response ... prg

Answer (score 3):

Use associations:

```
BarChart[
 Sort@AssociationThread[VertexList[edges], PageRankCentrality[edges]],
 ChartLabels -> Automatic
]
```

Comment: Szabolcs: Very nice idea to use the sort by association; I appreciate your approach too and it works well ... many thanks ... prg

Comment: @PRG, please take a [**tour**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). To learn that you can express your gratitude with upvotes :)