# How to position vertices according to clustering coefficient in a nice way?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I have a graph and I want to rank each vertex according to its local clustering coefficient. I have done the following:

```
g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[30, 0.25]];
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> Transpose[{RandomReal[1,
      VertexCount[g]],N[LocalClusteringCoefficient[g]]}]]
```

The y coordinate of each vertex is the local clustering coefficient, but I don't have a good way to choose the x coordinate so I use a random number. This creates (unsurprisingly) a cluttered ugly graph.

Is there any build-in way to have such a layout that is less ugly?

Comment: Can you rephrase the title? It's hardly understandable. As for the question in the body: I doubt that there is a good way to achieve this. Have you seen any plots which do the same things and look nice?

Comment: @Szabolcs I would gladly rephrase the title, but I'm not sure how to make it clearer. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you just mean "How to position vertices according to clustering coefficient in a nice way?"

Comment: I think it's just a typo (what Rahul said). Do you have any reason to believe that a nice layout is possible this way? My guess is that in general it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[30, 0.25]]
```

[image]

**"MultipartiteEmbedding"**

You can sort and split the `LocalClusteringCoefficient[g]` and use the part lengths as the suboption value for `"VertexPartition"` in `GraphEmbedding[g, {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> vertexpartition}]`. Replace the first coordinates with local clustering coefficients and normalize the second coordinates to get a list of `VertexCoordinates` where the horizontal axis values are local clustering coefficients:

```
v = SortBy[VertexList[g], LocalClusteringCoefficient[g, #] &];
lcc = Sort @ LocalClusteringCoefficient[g]; 
lengths = Length /@ Split[lcc];

ge = GraphEmbedding[g, {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> lengths}];

ge[[All, 2]] = 2 ge[[All, 2]] / VertexCount[g];
ge[[All, 1]] = LocalClusteringCoefficient[g, #] & /@ v;
ge = Reverse /@ ge;

Graph[v, EdgeList[g], VertexCoordinates -> ge, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc", ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

If you care only about the ordering of property values, you can have a less less cluttered picture

```
ge = Reverse /@ GraphEmbedding[g,
   {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> lengths}];

Graph[v, EdgeList[g], VertexCoordinates -> ge, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedEdge", 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexStyle -> White, 
 VertexSize -> .6, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart**

An alternative approach is to use `` GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart `` to get a nice visualization of vertex properties in a `PieChart` with sector sizes proportional to the property values:

```
gpc = GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[Graph[v, EdgeList[g]], 
 Automatic -> lcc /. 0 -> 10^-5, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{v, lcc}, {"RadialCenter", "RadialCallout"}]},
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Click on a vertex to highlight the edges incident to that vertex:

[image]

Highlight edges incident to selected vertices (using a modified version of `explode` from [this answer by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138105/125)):

```
highlight[v_][chart_, i : {__}] := ReplacePart[chart, 
  Position[chart, False][[Flatten[Position[v, #] & /@ i]]] -> True]


highlight[v][gpc, {6, 9}]
```

[image]

**Update: GraphPlot + VertexCoordinateRules**

Before version 12 updates, `VertexCoordinateRules` option of `GraphPlot` had the desired feature:

[image]

So, if you have access to a version prior to v12, you can do

```
vcrules = Thread[v -> lcc] /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, {Automatic, b}]
vcoords = GraphPlot[Rule @@@ EdgeList[g], VertexLabeling -> False, 
    VertexCoordinateRules -> vcrules][[1, 1, 1]];

Show[Graph[v, EdgeList[g], VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc", 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexStyle -> White, 
  VertexSize -> .9, ImageSize -> Large], Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {None, DeleteDuplicates@lcc}, 
 FrameTicks -> {N[Union[#, SameTest -> (Abs[#2 - #] <= .05 &)] & /@ {lcc, 
      lcc}], {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Note: `GridLines` and `FrameTicks` added to show that vertical coordinates are as specified.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for!!! Finding the coordinates of individual vertices is a bit unclear to me. You explain it above but I could not understand, for example, how you placed vertex 5 on the x-y coordinate system. How did you calculate the coordinate of vertex 5?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the answer to the exact question I asked, because it is not a built-in method, but I think it works pretty well.

Initially I asked mathematica to choose the x coordinates so that it minimizes the total edge lengths. Unsurprisingly it positioned all vertices on the same line.

So, I changed the objective function by adding the sum of the inverse distance between any two vertices and the result is not bad at all.

```
g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[30, 0.25]]
gg = AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[g], DirectedEdges -> True];
IM = IncidenceMatrix[gg];
CC = N[LocalClusteringCoefficient[g]];
coords = Transpose[{Table[x[i], {i, 30}], CC}];
eLenght = 
  Sum[e[[1]]^2 + e[[2]]^2, {e, 
    Transpose[{Table[x[i], {i, 30}].IM, CC.IM}]}];
invdists = 
  Total[1/DeleteCases[
     Flatten[Table[(p[[1]] - q[[1]])^2 + (p[[2]] - q[[2]])^2, {p, 
        coords}, {q, coords}]], 0.]];
minsol = Minimize[eLenght + 1/10000 invdists, 
    Table[x[i], {i, 30}]][[2]];
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> coords /. minsol]
```

This turns a graph like this:

[image]

to a graph like this:

[image]

I suspect that the minimum is not unique, but I am content with the result for now.